# Plotting on the same figure with a new handle

Tags: matlab

I want to display a series of images to a user. For each image request input from the user in the form of a mouse click on the image. Store the coordinates of each click in a matrix. Thus, in end having a matrix of dimension num_images x 2.

```
function main()
    clc;
    global agent_pos;
    ....
    for i=1:numel(img_names),
        imname = [ path_img img_names{i}];
        im0 = imread(imname);
        imageHandle =imshow(im0);%_____________displays the image
        set(gcf,'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1])
        set(imageHandle,'ButtonDownFcn',@ImageClickCallback);
        uiwait(gcf);
    end

end

function coordinates=ImageClickCallback ( objectHandle , eventData )
    axesHandle  = get(objectHandle,'Parent');
    coordinates = get(axesHandle,'CurrentPoint'); 
    coordinates = coordinates(1,1:2);
    global agent_pos;
    agent_pos=[agent_pos;coordinates]; %___ add these coordinates for each image
    close gcf;
end
```

My only issue here is that instead of creating a new window after user click , can I somehow display the image on the current figure itself.

I tried to replace close(gcf) with `clf` or `cla`. But the new image appears in a new window only that too after I close the current window. I think it's something related to the handle attached to the figure.

Comment: use 'cla' command to clear axes. axes object holds the plot data. You can read more about graphics object hierarchy here:http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics-objects.html

Comment: @User1551892 Hey! Thanks for the reply! But apparently that doesn't work, I too believed that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use uiresume instead of  closing the figure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can you please elucidate more.

Comment: You are closing the figure in order to unblock the uiwait and resume the for loop. But... This closes the figure you want to keep. So instead of unblock with gcf closing u can use an explicit unblocking command called uiresume.

Comment: Thanks for explantation!! On changing I seem to be getting this warning. I can't make much sense of it. Please check. `Warning: Error updating Text. Following is the chain of causes of the error:

 String must have valid interpreter syntax:
.\image_files\030.png
 
> In defaulterrorcallback at 12
  In uiwait at 81
  In main at 27 `